# Direction-aware transition with Ember Liquid Fire's {{liquid-with}} helper

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember app, I would like to make nice Liquid Fire transitions within the same route when the model of a dynamic route changes. Here's my router:

```
// app/router.js

Router.map(function() {
    this.route("campaigns", { path: "/" }, function() {
        this.route("campaign", { path: "/campaign/:election_year" });
    });
});
```

I would like the view to leave the screen to the left when switching to an `election_year` that is in the future (e.g., from `campaign/2008` to `campaign/2012`) and to the right the other way around.

My first thought was to use use the `{{liquid-outlet}}` and the `toModel` function in the `app/transitions.js` file, but Edward Faulkner (creator of Liquid Fire) says [in this thread](https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire/issues/15#issuecomment-109797554) that

> liquid-outlet does not handle model-to-model transitions on the same
>   route

and that I should use `{{liquid-with}}` instead. However I'm at a loss as to how to handle the directionality, i.e. make the view go left when `election_year` increases, and go right when it decreases. Any clues?

Comment: Maybe you can modify the `use` parameter of the liquid-width:

`{{#liquid-with campaigns as campaign use=direction}}` (set `direction` to  `toLeft` or `toRight`)

Comment: Does that mean I would have to add some computed property `direction`  to the `campaign` controller? But how would that property know whether `election_year` is increasing or decreasing?

Comment: The `willTransition` hook could work to change the `direction` property: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_willTransition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a `liquid-with` (or `liquid-bind`) helper, there is not necessarily a route or model involved in the animation, and so constraints like `toRoute` or `toModel` do not apply. Instead, you can use `toValue` which will match against whatever you're passing into the helper.

Assuming you're passing a `Campaign` model to `liquid-with`, you could use a rule like this in `transitions.js`:

```
this.transition(
  this.toValue(function(newValue, oldValue) {
    return newValue instanceof Campaign &&
           oldValue instanceof Campaign &&
           newValue.electionYear > oldValue.electionYear
  }),
  this.use('toLeft'),
  this.reverse('toRight')
)
```

Explanation:

We have a constraint, an animation to use when it matches (`toLeft`), and an animation to use when it matches with "to" and "from" reversed (`toRight`),

All the rule constraints (including `toValue`, `fromRoute`, etc) can accept:

- simple values like `toValue(42)` or `toRoute('posts')` that will be compared with `===`
- regular expressions like `toRoute(/unicorn/)`
- functions that test the value, like `toValue(n => n > 1)`.
- functions that compare the value and the "other value", like

  ```
  toValue((newThing, oldThing) => newThing.betterThan(oldThing))
  ```

The final case is what we're using in the solution above.

(We are continuing to refine these APIs. In this particular case, I think we should add an explicit name for the comparison rule, like `this.compareValues(function(oldValue, newValue){...})`, instead of just overloading `toValue` to also do comparison. But this should not affect your solution, as I'm not going to break the existing behavior in the foreseeable future.)

Comment: Excellent answer. Is there a way to make the transition dependent on user-input? I'd like to have a "toLeft" transition whenever the user clicks on a "next" button and a "toRight" transition for the "previous" button.

Comment: It's easier and more future-proof to do something like I described above. You necessarily have enough information to know which is the next model to the current model, so you can test for that by looking at the two models.

Comment: That way, even if you change your UI, the intent is preserved. Also consider that users may navigate via the back button, in which case there is never a click on the "previous" button.